# Making a reified field optional in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Currently trying to optimize code usage between two functions that do the exact same thing, but accept different inputs yet have the same JVM signature.

These are basic helpers, and this issue can easily be worked around by using a different name for each function, but the current goal is to make them more intuitive.

Example functions are as follows:

Function that uses a default `<T>` type inherited from the current class instance:

```kotlin
suspend inline fun forGeneric(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
    sharedFlow.collect(collector)
}
```

Function that accepts a specific `<K>` type that extends `<T>`:

```kotlin
suspend inline fun <reified K : T> forSpecific(collector: FlowCollector<K>) {
    sharedFlow.filterIsInstance<K>().collect(collector)
}
```

Where `sharedFlow` is an internal `SharedFlow` field.

These are used from the class they're inherited from as follows:

```kotlin
MyClass.forGeneric { it: MyGenericValue ->
    when (it) {
        is MySpecificValue -> (...)
        is (...)
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

```kotlin
MyClass.forSpecific<MySpecificValue> { it: MySpecificValue ->
    // do stuff here
}
```

Where `MyGenericValue` is `<T>` and `MySpecificValue` is `<K>` and extends from `MyGenericValue`.

The goal is for both to have the exact same name, but the only difference being the developer specifying a type or not. If no type is specified, it uses the "main" parent type by default, otherwise it uses the specified type.

Example of what is being attempted using the same scenarios above:

```kotlin
MyClass.for { it: MyGenericValue ->
    when (it) {
        is MySpecificValue -> (...)
        is (...)
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

```kotlin
MyClass.for<MySpecificValue> { it: MySpecificValue ->
    // do stuff here
}
```

And the base function would be something like this (I do know this isn't correct, but it's meant to be an example):

```kotlin
suspend inline fun <reified K : T> forSpecific(collector: FlowCollector<K>) {
    if (K == null) {
        sharedFlow.collect(collector)
    } else {
        sharedFlow.filterIsInstance<K>().collect(collector)
    }
}
```

Not really sure this is even possible, but searching for this topic proved to be a difficult task since my lack of deep knowledge in the area always lead me to generic, or just unrelated examples/answers in StackOverflow.

I know there might be a way to also work around this by passing the type class as a function parameter instead of reified type (`<...>` vs `fun(T::java.class, ...)`), but that is not the real goal here, the preference is to use the structure above if it is possible.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but do you need `forGeneric`? Isn't every `K` also a `T`?

Comment: @fafl That is for not having to specify the type at all, otherwise the dev would have to use it as `MyClass.forSpecific<MyGenericValue>(...)` instead of `MyClass.forGeneric(...)`, which he can still do in either case, but there would be no advantage whatsoever. again, these are merely helper functions, the objective is to keep making them easier and simpler to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may look a little weird, but it's the only workaround I could think of. You can add an unused dummy `Unit` argument to one of the overloads:

```
suspend fun forSomething(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
    sharedFlow.collect(collector)
}

suspend inline fun <reified K: T> forSomething(unit: Unit = Unit, collector: FlowCollector<K>) {
    sharedFlow.filterIsInstance<K>().collect(collector)
}
```

Comment: Just tested and works perfectly! Obviously the best option would be to not have that extra parameter to change the signature, but for the purpose of my question this is a great compromise to have given the benefit it provides. Unless someone else provides an even better solution then this one takes the cake, thanks!